# QString split() function with QRegExp strange behaviour

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qstring, qregexp

I have some text like this:

```
"1.801908\t20.439980\t\r\n25.822865\t20.439305\t\r\n26.113739\t4.069647\t\r\n1.800252\t4.301690\t\r\n"
```

I want to split this text by lines and then by tabs. I am using `QString split()` function and `QRegExp` to do that in this way:

```
QStringList rows = text.split(QRegExp("[\r\n]"), QString::SkipEmptyParts);
QStringList cols = rows.at(0).split(QRegExp("[ \t]"), QString::SkipEmptyParts);
```

But what I got in `cols` is just one item:

```
  "1.801908\920.439980\9"
```

As I understand, the first split replaced all the `\t` characters with `\9`. But I don't understand why and how to fix that. Any explanation?

Comment: Can't reproduce here. I got ("1.801908", "20.439980") when I qDebug() << cols;

Comment: Can't reproduce it too, my output is correct.